# Print to PDF in QGIS 3.0 from layout cuts off a strip of the bottom and right hand sides

Tags: print-composer, qgis-3, pdf, qgis-print-layouts

As per the title. It happens every time I export it through print to pdf. Doesn't matter if I choose "microsoft print to pdf" or "adobe pdf".

My map is within the canvas dimensions. When I select Export to PDF, it works fine. I use print to pdf because it comes out as a smaller file size for sending via email and placing in documents as compared to export to PDF which outputs massive PDF file sizes.

The canvas size is A4, the print to pdf preferences are set to A4.

Anyone else have this problem?

Comment: I'm having the same problem, but also when I send to a printer. In my case it just leaves off a part at the bottom. I've tried different printers, but that didn't help.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/148945)

Comment: Perhaps a similar problem to mine--strips of the text are cut off (not labels, only page layout text elements).